# Storing XML and performing XPath queries directly against Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

**Is there a way to store and retrieve XML in Redis as XML, and then also to perform an XPath query in Redis?**

I have a .NET 4.8 application is ***very*** XML dependent. I send requests with XML to third parties, get responses back in XML, and store that information in Redis, as a string. For reference, I use StackExchange.Redis.

Sometimes I might only need a single node from a much larger response and wish to retrieve it via an XPath query against a key.

Take this as an example:

```xml
<Movies>
  <Movie Id="1" Year="1989"><Title><![CDATA[Lethal Weapon 2]]></Title></Movie>
  <Movie Id="2" Year="1998"><Title><![CDATA[Rush Hour]]></Title></Movie>
  ...
  <Movie Id="6340" Year="2009"><Title><![CDATA[Avatar]]></Title></Movie>
</Movies>
```

Currently, the only way to do that would be to perform a GET on the Redis key, deserialize the string into XML (and perhaps then deserialize it to an object), and *then* perform an XPath 1.1 or lambda query on the resulting object.

I've looked and I can't see anything which allows such a thing, but I *can* see JSON modules (such as [RedisJSON](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/)) which would support JSONPath.

The 'easy' solution might be to simply migrate from XML to JSON and then use one of those modules module, but then I'd still have lots of XML to deal with from third party systems, and I'd have two problems.

Another alternative to better manage a large result set might be to split out the Movies object into a list so that every Movie is an item, but then I'd still need to retrieve the entire list in order to identify a single item.

Answer (score -2):

You can use xml linq.  CDATA needs to be capital letter so I replace all the values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {

        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            xml = xml.Replace("CData", "CDATA");

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement xMovies = doc.Descendants("Movies").FirstOrDefault();

            List<Movie> movies = xMovies.Elements("Movie")
                .Select(x => new Movie() { id = (int)x.Attribute("Id"), year = (int)x.Attribute("Year"), title = (string)x.Element("Title") })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Movie
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't answer my question at all. I know *how* to perform XML parsing, performing XPath queries or lambda searches, but my question - as noted in the title and the first line is "Is there a way to ***store and retrieve XML in Redis as XML***, and then also to ***perform an XPath query in Redis***?" What you've shown me is deserializing XML from a file into a string and then into class which is ***exactly*** what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Why did you add the tag c# to the posting?

Comment: Because, as per the question, I'm using [`StackExchange.Redis`](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/) and would like to know if it's feasible either using that package or something else, and whether there may be a better way of achieving my goals.

Comment: You can connect to you database, query the xml, parse with my code, and then store data in Redis.  See following for connection : https://redis.io/docs/clients/dotnet/

Comment: That *still* doesn't answer my question. I'm looking to store XML as an XML datatype in redis, and also be able to query Redis directly using XPath to return a subset of the larger object. What your answer boils down to is "here's how you can store XML as a string, read it out, parse to XML, and then deserialize into objects". As I clearly stated, ***this is what I already do***. `NRedisStack` also does not offer this.